# F2py default argument

Tags: option-type, overloading, f2py

I want to build a function with default arguments. However, any of the following simple methods fail to compile with F2PY printing the following simple and no-informing error message "error: f2py target file '/tmp/....' not generated".

1st using optional

```
  module a
  contains

  integer function func(j)
    implicit none
    integer, optional :: j

    if(present(j)) then
      func = j
    else
      func = 0
    endif
  end function 

  end module
```

The other is function overloading using interface

```
  module test
    interface func
      module procedure :: func0, func1
    end interface
  contains

  integer function func0()
    implicit none
    func0 = 0
  end function 

  integer function func1(j)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: j
    func1 = j
  end function
  end module
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the expression using the F2PY directive.

```
integer function func(j)
  implicit none
  integer :: j
  !f2py integer :: j = 0

  func = j
end function
```